# Ark of the Covenant

Tags: ark-of-the-covenant

Is it possible to find the Ark of the Covenant? According to some reports, it is hidden in a cave in the Dumghe Mountains in Africa; other report mention a Lake Qum. Where this lake could be? The real question however is not where, but why? Would you know why the Ark of the Covenant is hidden?

Comment: This question is asking for speculation. It's impossible to prove a negative. The only way to conclusively answer this question would be to find it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding an artifact, and not about Christianity.

Comment: @Flimzy. The question is not about finding an artifact at all. It is about doctrine. There are Christians that believe that they have been guarding the Ark since Queen Sheba brought it to Ethiopia. It forms part of their religious beliefs. Their form of Christianity is also Christianity not only yours. It might be interesting to hear how they would answer the question of 'why'? Very good question.

Comment: @gideonmarx: I think a good question could be asked about the Ark of the Covenant along those lines. This is not that question.

Comment: Everyone out there. Please do not downvote as a kneejerk every time you do not understand or disagree with something. And have the courage to say why you downvoted.

Comment: @Flimzy. 'The real question however is not where, but why?' I think it is a fantastic question to ask the Ethiopians who hold this belief. 'Why are you hiding the ark?' or 'Why do you pretend to hide the ark?' But that is for them to answer and I haven't seen many of them on this site.

Comment: @gideonmarx: That is also an unanswerable question... as to answer that, first we must find out who is indeed hiding the ark, then ask them. But everyone who claims to be hiding the ark refuses to provide proof.

Comment: @Flimzy. I read an explanation from one of their 'priests' years ago and it was something like 'God told them to keep it safe' until . . . can't remember. Ethiopia is now a major tourist destination especially for Christians and they all come back enlightened and with 974 photos. As for proof in religion . . . can the Roman Catholic Church prove that the Vatican was built on the grave of the Apostle Peter? That is the whole point of faith based religion and that is what makes this case interesting. Why, in their religious thinking, are they hiding the ark? So we learn about other Christians.

Comment: @gideonmarx: There are many questions in Christianity which cannot be proven. And every one of them makes for many bad qeustions for this site. This question is one of them.

Comment: @Flimzy. The solution is obviously that the site must be changed to disallow these 'bad questions'. Maybe a team of experts can work on what in Christianity can be 'proven' and eliminate all questions that do not fall within this doctrine.

Comment: @gideonmarx: I don't see the problem you're describing. This question was already closed... is there something else you think ought to be done?

Comment: Closed? Who closed it? These are very interesting Christians and it would be nice to learn more about them.

Comment: I completely fail to see how the help center rules out Ethiopian Christians that believe they have the ark. It is completely within the scope. (The Roman Catholics believe they have the grave of the Apostle Peter and they are not ruled out.) Unhold the question!

Comment: II Maccabees 2:6

Answer (score 3):

It is believed that the Babylonians took the Ark during their conquest of Isreal. This belief is also disputed by those who believe it was hidden by the Jews so that it would not be carried off, but that no one knows where the Jews hid it. There is no (historical and factual) written information about where the ark went after the Babylonian conquest, and nobody has it in their possession, so it is "lost", or hidden. It has not been found by man, and we do not even know if it even still exists.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_of_the_Covenant#The_Babylonian_Conquest_and_aftermath

As for whether or not it is possible to find the Ark, it will be possible to find it until there is sufficient historical evidence to show beyond a shadow of a doubt that it no longer exists. However, the possibility becomes slimmer and slimmer the more people search for it and fail to find it.

If you are asking why God would have the ark remain hidden or be destroyed, mere men can only speculate. You will never have a definite answer to this question while you live on Earth, unless God decides, for some reason, to speak directly with you about this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Archaeologists have unearthed many items related to the Bible that we never knew still existed. Based on that, it's possible the Ark could still be uncovered in a dig somewhere.

However, the question you meant to ask, I think, is: "Do we have enough information to hunt down and find the Ark?" And the answer is simply No, we do not. We don't have even the country name or how it got "lost."